# How to display and enable extra symbols on standard keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, android-12, oppo-coloros

When switching from Huawei's Android 8.0 to Oppo's Android 12 I noticed a keyboard problem that I'm unable to solve.

First, here is how the keyboard on Android 8.0 looked like:
[image: Android 8.0 keyboard on Huawei P10 Lite]

Then, here is how the keyboard on Android 12 looks like:
[image: Android 12 (ColorOS 12.1) keyboard on Oppo X5 Lite]

You see that on the "old" keyboard there are additional symbols above the letters (like `'` on <kbd>c</kbd> that is not displayed on the new keyboard.
However it's not just that the symbol isn't displayed, it's also not available on long-press of <kbd>c</kbd>.

So my simple question is:
*How can I get the "old layout" on my new phone?*

Comment: The used keyboard is simply another app. A lot of manufacturer modify the standard keyboard app. You can simply install a different keyboard app from Play Store or even try to extract keyboard app form your old phone and migrate it to the new phone.

Comment: I'm rather sure both are "gboard".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assuming both are [Gboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin), the feature is called "Long press for symbols" and unrelated to the Android versions.**

Steps to change the setting:

1. Open Gboard's Settings (the cog-wheel icon on the keyboard)

   - Or alternatively from Android Settings - System - Languages & input - On-screen keyboard - Gboard (adjust the step according to each manufacturer's customization)
2. Select "Preferences"
3. Scroll down to "Key press" and toggle the "Long press for symbols" switch.

Comment: That's it! However the naming of the option is somewhat stupid, as a long press offers alternate symbols (call them "letters with diacritical marks") even without having set that option. I wonder why that wasn't set by default as it's a real pain to type with that keyboard...